# UIAlertviewController crashes in IOS8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, ios8.3

I was using `UIAlertView` but In IOS 8.3 i changed to `UIAlertViewController` Because `UIAlertview` was not working But `UIAlertViewController` Crash with the error

```
'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation',
reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with 
         the application, and 
         [ChartsTableViewController2_iPhone shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
```

Don't know what to do please help me.

Comment: Please, put your code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to subclass UIAlertController and add this code. Hope it helps.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: I was using a UIAlertView on iPad Pro (9.1) in a landscape-only app, and I was getting this crash, and this answer fixed it for me.